# Using data from php in angular5

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Pls am new to angular, I sent data from my angular to my PHP in my registration page, and I also did server-side validation, but my problem is how can I use the data I got like of the response is 'am error occur'  then I can do something but if the response is 'ok' then I can do something else,

I used this to send data

```
this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1/Ana/index.php', 
  {name: name, username: username, password: password})
.map(res => res.json())
.subscribe(res => this.getit = res);
```

I was able to send and get a response back but how can I use it like when doing server-side validation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*First time I misunderstood your question*

I guess you're trying to check if the server validation was sucessful or not?

In that case, if you designed it correctly, you can use the following [code](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response) (straight from the docs of Angular)

```
http
  .get<ItemsResponse>('/api/items')
  .subscribe(
    // Successful responses call the first callback.
    data => {...},
    // Errors will call this callback instead:
    err => {
      console.log('Something went wrong!');
    }
  );
```

Comment: Yes that's what am trying to do